# Multiple authentication modes within one WebApplication

Tags: infrastructure, configuration

I've one web application on SharePoint 2010. I've root site collection `MainSite`. Also I have another site collection`SubSite` hosted on http://MainSite/SubSite.

**Question:** Is it possible to have Anonymous authentication for `MainSite` and Claims-based for `SubSite` within one WebApp? Or I have to use different web apps for this?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is Yes! you would configure you Web Application to use claims based authentication and then enable Anonymous access on the root site collection and then turn it off for the subsite. See the documentation here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806886.aspx